# Call to original page from log in form

Tags: javascript, php, return, forms

1. I have an index page that gives the user the opportunity to log in. If the user logs in, they will be redirected to a php login form. Once the submit the information this login form posts to itself and verifies the user information and then starts a session. After the session is started I want the user to be redirected back to the page that they originally clicked the login link from.

What would be the best and other possible ways to implement this? 
I am thinking of some sort of global array to hold there return address.

2 If on the index page the user were to be typing in other fields for a form, and then log in, what would be the best way to assure that the information they have already entered is still there?

I am thinking about having these values automatically stored on an array and then reloaded with a new page.

2a What if instead of fields they are uploading files?

3 How does one make a log in page that is centered on the middle of the browser, above the other content without destroying it? 
-I assume this would be a javascript function
-Would I still be able to use php self post on this?

I am more in need of psydo-code/conventions then actual code examples.

Thanks

Comment: About the return to the original URL, just send the user back to the referer ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']). If you need the POSTed data, you could serialize it and send it back as a GET parameter.

I would suggest you use Ajax, though.

Comment: As @Victor say, this whole thing screams for a ajax solution.

Comment: Would a possible AJax solution go like this:  1. Have a link to a login that triggers a javascript script 2. this javascript would then run the form?

Comment: 2- If they half fill out a form, then don't submit it and log in then that's entirely their fault